# why do i get this error when i play .wav sound file using eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, audio

whenever i try to play a .wav or .mp3 sound file USING ECLIPSE IDE i get
this error, check the code(it's very simple why would i get errors?) :

```
import sun.audio.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Sound {
 String Filename = "someSound.wav";
    InputStream in;
    AudioStream as;

public Sound() {
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(Filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        as = new AudioStream(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AudioPlayer.player.start(as);
    AudioPlayer.player.stop(as);

}

static public void main(String[] args) {
    Sound s = new Sound();
}}
```

and this is the exception :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: someSound.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at Sound.<init>(Sound.java:14)
at Sound.main(Sound.java:10)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(AudioStream.java:65)
    at Sound.<init>(Sound.java:19)
    at Sound.main(Sound.java:10)
```

so what's the problem?

edit 1 :

i also tried to change the path to
C:\Users\Rev3rse\workspace\Project1\src\someSound.wav

and i got a diffrent excpetion check it :

```
java.io.IOException: could not create audio stream from input stream
at sun.audio.AudioStream.<init>(AudioStream.java:82)
at Sound.<init>(Sound.java:16)
at Sound.main(Sound.java:26)
```

Comment: Where did `someSound.wav` resides? It is clear that jvm can't find that file. Give proper path to that file.

Answer (score 0):

FileInputStream expects the file path to be partitioned with double slashes.So instead of giving the source path as C:\Users\Rev3rse\workspace\Project1\src\someSound.wav use double slashes for the partition.

HOPE IT WORKS !!!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating the InputStream from a resource instead so you are not tied down to a path.  Something like:

```
in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("someSound.wav");
```

That eliminates the path and creates one less headache for you the developer to worry about.

Comment: Has anyone had a resolution to this?  I've tried both a file name and a resource, and I get the same error message.  I've tried different .wav files, and the files I've tried have played fine in existing players (Dragon, VLC, Windows Media Player).  The error message is singularly uninformative.